# Arduino how to make function that returns fixed size array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, arduino

I'm trying to create function that returns an array but when using

```
int x[5];

void setup() {
  x = getX();
}

int * getX(){
  return {1,1,1,1,1};
}
```

I get: **incompatible types in assignment of 'int*' to 'int [5]'**

Comment: To make assignment work on arrays you have to use `std::array`. In `C` there is no such feature like assignment between arrays so you have to use C++ specific feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Arduino-IDE may not support C++'s `std::array` like mentioned in a comment, but you can do it like:

```
int* get() {
    static int my_array[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    return my_array;
}
```

It's no possible to reasign an array like you've tried in your `setup` function.

Consider using:

```
int* x = nullptr;

void setup() {
    x = get();
}
```

I've to point out, that this is not best practice. Maybe you can give some more information to find a better solution.